# Is "a" mandatory in "I'm a whole new (Name)"?

Tags: grammaticality, articles, proper-nouns, indefinite-articles

Let's say, your name is Kate and you say "I'm a whole new Kate!"

Now, can you drop "a" and say "I'm whole new Kate!"?

Or is it mandatory to keep it?

Comment: [Old John is Dead. I Am New John](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8cz6ZwEACAAJ&dq=%22I+am+new+John%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xoG2UJbZBNOk0AWI34DoDg&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAA). *That* sounds like a competent speaker "playing" with language, but adding "whole" would just make it sound like a bad translation.

Comment: After the surgeons re-attached her severed thumb, Kate might exclaim: "I'm whole!"

Comment: It's mandatory. Because she's not stating her name, she's stating a kind of thing, a particular kind of thing (which happens to be herself, labeled with her name).

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't drop the indefinite article. The name Kate is in general a proper noun but in this type of constructs it becomes a common noun. It begins to denote not *the* Kate, but a whole class of "Kate"s. *A Kate* is any instance of the class Kate — such as "the angry Kate", "the five-year-old Kate", "the Kate now", "the Kate you're in love with" etc. As a common noun, it requires an indefinite article in this context:

> I'm a whole new Kate.

Comment: So is it safe to say that you always need an article before a proper noun having a modifying adjective?

Comment: @user27275: If the adjective is not part of the name, then yes. I'm Red John. But I am a happy Kate.

Comment: Well, the "Red" in "Red John" is not an adjective in the first place, but his first name, ain't it? Maybe you'd want to have some other example like "Great Britain"?

Comment: @user27275: I'm not sure if Red in Red John is his first name.

Answer (score 1):

No. The article is needed, as per Armen's analysis. "I'm whole new Kate" would mean that your name is...

> Whole New Kate

Comment: Or yuo're telling the new Kate that you're whole: "I'm whole, new Kate."